# Assets not found in Railo Express

Tags: image, coldfusion, jetty, assets, railo

I downloaded and extracted railo express 4.2.1 to the base of my C: drive on windows 7.  I started the application without making any configuration changes as I don't know what I would need to change.  I created a CustomerService folder inside the webapps/root directory which holds my FW/1 customer service application.  The ColdFusion code runs perfect however when I try to link to any other kind of resource such as css, js or image files they are not found. If I place an image in the CustomerService/assets/images/icons folder and add a link to it using  the image does not show up (broken link icon instead).  If I right click and view image I get a page that says:

Problem accessing /customerservice/assets/images/icons/add.png. Reason:

Not Found

Powered by Jetty://

The url path for the image that is displayed in the address bar is:

```
http://localhost:8888/customerservice/assets/images/icons/add.png
```

which from my understanding is correct and I have verified that the add.png image is in the icons folder of the images folder for the assets folder which is in the CustomerService folder.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Do I need to configure something in the Railo server or web administrators or in Jetty some how?  If so what and how do I do that?

Thanks,

Jason Presley

Comment: When you use the internal server on Railo, it is case sensitive. That may be the issue. I see that you have "CustomerService" in camel case.

Comment: That did it.  I had the folder as CustomerService but in the url was calling customerservice.  Thank you so much James!

Answer (score 0):

When you use the internal server on Railo, it is case sensitive. That may be the issue. I see that you have "CustomerService" in camel case